# Tunnel outbound HTTP over inbound socket connection

Tags: proxy

** This question might belong on SF except for one of the constraints below (not having admin rights on one machine) **

At my work I have two machines, A and B.  Machine A is my primary development machine.  It is completely disconnected from the corporate network.  Machine B is connected and is used primarily for email and web access.  It is rather locked down - I don't have admin rights and it does not accept inbound connections.  I cannot run programs I download, however I have Visual Studio 2005 and can create and run executables which works great (notwithstanding lack of admin rights).

I have an ad-hoc wireless network between the two and I'm able to transfer files via standard Windows shares so long as I browse from Machine B to a share on Machine A.  I am also able to browse to websites hosted on Machine A, including non-standard port numbers (ie, http://machineb:12121/).

My goal is to create some sort of connection initiated by Machine B to Machine A which then grants me internet access on Machine A, presumably by setting up a proxy server on Machine B.  However, I would need source code to the proxy server so I could build & run it locally.

My initial thought is to create two apps, one to run on Machine B and pings the app on A (which listens for local requests on port 80), and when it receives a response (containing a URL I guess) to use a HttpWebRequest object to hit that URL and then pass that data back... but I can see this getting complicated real quick.

Any suggestions to get me started?

Answer (score 1):

Any number of open source web proxies will do what you're asking. You can do it with apache, and mod_proxy, even.

However, were I your admin, and I caught you tunnelling access out of a machine I'd specifically prohibited access from/to, I would do such things to you that other programmers would weep at the very mention of your name. Tread lightly.

Comment: On what machine would the web proxy run?  I don't understand how that would help the issue with Machine B blocking inbound connections, and if the proxy ran on Machine A then how does the proxy communicate with Machine B?  Thanks.

Your concern about sysadmins etc is noted.